# vb.net graphics drawimage out of memory

Tags: .net, vb.net

i try to reduce image file size, at first everything is working fine
but after reduce 14th-15th file, code throw error "out of memory"
at `pic.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height)`
and `jpeg.Save(exePath & "\" & dir_file & re12.Name, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)`

i already add `tp.Dispose()` & `pic.Dispose()` but it doesn't work

this is my code

```
        Private Sub imgreduce_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles imgreduce.DoWork
                Dim reduce12 = New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(exePath & "\" & dir_file).GetFiles("file_*.jpeg").OrderBy(Function(x) x.Name)
                For Each re12 As System.IO.FileInfo In reduce12                        
                    Dim jpeg As Image = Image.FromFile(exePath & "\" & dir_file & re12.Name)
                    Dim tp As Bitmap = reduce(jpeg, jpeg.Width, jpeg.Height)
                    jpeg.Dispose()
                    jpeg = tp
                    jpeg.Save(exePath & "\" & dir_file & re12.Name, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
                Next
            End Sub

       Private Function reduce(ByVal img As Image, ByVal width As Integer, ByVal height As Integer) As Image
            Dim imaf As New Bitmap(width, height)
            Dim pic As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(imaf)
            pic.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
            pic.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height)
            Return imaf
        End Function
```

Comment: Missing Dispose() call after the Save(), that won't last long.  Do practice using the `Using` statement.

Comment: It's also not clear how this would reduce the image size. You're loading JPEG files, then the Image is drawn into another Bitmap of the same size and saved to another file. Is that all this procedure is supposed to do?

Comment: @Jimi image size 10 MB turn to 2-3 MB after using this code sir, it's working

Comment: @HansPassant `Dispose()` after `Save()` not working sir, it still give me `out of memory` at `pic.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height)`

Comment: Dispose this too `Dim pic As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(imaf)`, As mentioned, create the disposable objects in `Using..End Using` block.

Comment: Bottom line: always dispose _all_ .NET types that use GDI+ objects (Graphics, Pen, Brush, Image, etc).  The code shown here might just be the symptom and not the cause - especially if the _entire app_ is not disposing of GDI+ objects.  There is a hard limit to the number of GDI+ objects your process can have (default is 10,000); create any more, and you get the OOM exception.

Comment: Start by making sure that every object that supports it is disposed, as has already been suggested. If you still have the same issue, you may need to explicitly call `GC.Collect` intermittently. That should generally be avoided but creating lots of `Images` is the one scenario where I've seen it be necessary. You might call it after every tenth call to `reduce`, for instance, or you might catch those out of memory exceptions and call it then.

Comment: Why assign `tp` to `jpeg` and then call `Save` on `jpeg` when you could just call `Save` on `tp`?

Comment: guys using statement not working.. how can i do now? https://i.imgur.com/FiELNtU.png still give me `out of memory`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

problem solved!

```
Private Sub imgreduce_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles imgreduce.DoWork
     Dim reduce12 = New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(exePath & "\" & dir_file).GetFiles("file_*.jpeg").OrderBy(Function(x) x.Name)
     For Each re12 As System.IO.FileInfo In reduce12
     Dim jpeg As Image = Image.FromFile(exePath & "\" & dir_file & re12.Name)
     Using newImage As Bitmap = New Bitmap(reduce(jpeg, jpeg.Width, jpeg.Height))
          jpeg.Dispose()
          jpeg = newImage
          jpeg.Save(exePath & "\" & dir_file & re12.Name, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
          jpeg.Dispose()
          newImage.Dispose()
          GC.Collect()
     End Using
     jpeg.Dispose()
     GC.Collect()
     Next
End Sub

Private Function reduce(ByVal img As Image, ByVal width As Integer, ByVal height As Integer) As Image
     GC.Collect()
     Dim imaf As Bitmap = New Bitmap(width, height)
     Using pic As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(imaf)
         pic.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
         pic.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height)
         GC.Collect()
     End Using
     Return imaf
     imaf.Dispose()
     GC.Collect()
End Function
```